# Bash terminal output - highlight lines containing some text

Tags: bash, shell

When I get output in bash I get my standard 2 colour screen. Is there any way I can, by default, highlight a line if it contains some key text output?

E.g. if it contains the word "FAIL" then the line is coloured red.

I’ve read this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46562/how-do-you-colorize-only-some-keywords-for-a-bash-script
but am looking for something simpler than having to write a wrapper script which I’d inevitably have to debug at some time in the future.

Comment: Depending on your needs, coloring the standard error stream might actually be preferable to looking for keywords. I'm a big fan of [stderred](https://github.com/sickill/stderred) for this.

Answer (score 11):

For a simple workaround, pipe it through `grep --color` to turn some words red.

Add a fallback like `^` to print lines which do not contain any matches otherwise.

```
grep --color -e 'FAIL' -e '^' <<<$'Foo\nBar FAIL Baz\nIck'
```

[Grep output with multiple Colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236005/grep-output-with-multiple-colors) describes a hack for getting multiple colors if you need that.

Comment: ++, but as an aside: even though it _should_ work, your command _crashes_ the BSD `grep` v2.5.1 on macOS 10.12.4 (it works fine with the same `grep` version on PC-BSD 10.1, for instance).

Comment: @mklement0 That's curious! It only seems to crash after completing, but still of course not a Good Thing.

Comment: `grep -e '.*' -e '^'` also crashes, but the coloring looks like it somehow gets stuck in the second `-e` after the first line. Removing the `--color` option avoids the crash.

Answer (score 3):

If you're happy to install a BASH script and `ack`, the `hhlighter` package has useful default colours and an easy interface https://github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter:

[image: hhighlight example]

You can use it like so to highlight rows that start with `FAIL`:

```
h -i 'FAIL.*'
```

or that contain `FAIL`:

```
h -i '.*FAIL.*'
```

or for various common log entries:

```
h -i '.*FAIL.*' '.*PASS.*' '.*WARN.*'
```

Comment: First helpful answer to this topic (even to similar stackoverflow questions)! Possibility to highlight different words in different colors. Works on macos with iTerm2 and zsh 

Answer (score 2):

Building on tripleee's answer, following command will highlight the matching line red and preserve the other lines:

```
 your_command | grep --color -e ".*FAIL.*" -e "^"
```

If you prefer a completely inverted line, with gnu grep:

```
 your_command | GREP_COLORS='mt=7' grep --color -e ".*FAIL.*" -e "^"
```

(updated with mklement0 feedback)

Comment: The first command _duplicates_ tripleee's answer (except for using a pipeline instead of a here-string).  The 2nd command is helpful, except that you should mention that it requires _GNU_ `grep` (won't work on BSD/macOS, for instance) and perhaps make it clearer that the _entire line_ is inverted.

Answer (score 2):

This will highlight not only a word, but the whole line:

```
echo "foo bar error baz" | egrep --color '*.FAIL.*|$'
```

A search phrase should be enclosed by `.*` on either side. It will cause highlighting before and after the search word or phrase.

### References

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330613/341457
2. [How .* (dot star) works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666768/how-dot-star-works)

Answer (score 0):

add into your .profile or .bashrc following lines:

```
hilite() {
    REGEX_SED=$(echo $1 | sed "s/[|()]/\\\&/g");
    sed "s/$REGEX_SED/\x1b[7m&\x1b[0m/g"
}
```

then * you can enter something like this:

```
cat example.txt | hilite FAIL
```

or

```
grep FAIL example.txt | hilite FAILURE
```

- once you have to execute a "source .profile" or ". .bashrc"  or a second login, to make it effective