# How can I upload multiple pattern files using artifactory/jfrog in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jfrog-cli

I am trying to upload multiple patterns like .zip and .tar.gz using Artifactory/Jfrog Files in Jenkins.

here is my code

```
                def uploadSpec = """{
                "files": [
                {
                    "pattern": "(*.zip | *.tar.gz)",
                    "target": "${upload_loc}/${BRANCH_NAME}/",
                    "recursive": "true",
                    "flat": "false",
                    "props": "Version=${Version};Branch=${BRANCH_NAME}"
                }
                ]
                }"""
```

I tried above syntax and it's not working for me, it says 0 artifcats found. can any one suggest if they encounter similar scenario.

Thanks and Regards
Saint

Comment: Are you sure you are running the upload command in the same directory where your files are present?

Comment: in regexp, wildcard is `.*` (`.` stands for "any character" and `*` stands for "any number of times"), not just `*` so this is invalid. You also need to enable regexp by using `"regexp": "true"` in your spec.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666768/how-dot-star-works for an explanation of the regex syntax in this case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have 2 options:

Option 1 - Use a regular expression to describe your patterns.

In your example something like this should work:

```
    ...
    "pattern": "(.*\.zip|.*\.tar\.gz)",
    "regexp":"true",
    ...
```

Note that if you do so, you have to add the flag **regexp=true**.

(I use [this](https://regex101.com/) website to test my expressions. note that you have to check golang as your flavor)

Option 2 - Use multiple files in a single spec (what I would probably do in your case).

In your example something like this should work:

```
..."files": [
                {
                    "pattern": "*.tar.gz",
                    "target": "${upload_loc}/${BRANCH_NAME}/",
                    "recursive": "true",
                    "flat": "false",
                    "props": "Version=1"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "*.zip",
                    "target": "${upload_loc}/${BRANCH_NAME}/",
                    "recursive": "true",
                    "flat": "false",
                    "props": "Version=1"
                }
                ]...
```

Comment: I opted for the 1st option (well done!), but i receive this odd error: `WorkflowScript: 75: unexpected char: '\'` at startup. My regexp is `"pattern": "(.*\.zip|.*\.war|pom.xml)"`